# Weird noise-like textures on roughness textured surface? (Cycle render)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction, roughness

So I have this metal object that has roughness textures on it. It looks okay on the viewport.
[image]
[image]

But when I render it somehow there are some noise textures on it.

[image]
[image: Close Up]

The noise especially is on the shaded side.

I tried to render without all the things around it incase the reflections of the object is what caused it, but the weird textures are still there.

[image]

This is the render setting and the composite I use. Increasing the samples to 256 or even 500 didn't do the trick.
[image]
[image]

This is my first time rendering with cycles so I don't know if there is something that I do wrong, but I've tried everything I found about trying to denoise renders but it doesn't solve them. So I don't really know what went wrong here, I'd appreciate for any clues, been stumped on this for days.